# How to know if the line is empty while reading char by char in PHP

Tags: php, fgetc

How do I differentiate between an empty line and an endofline in PHP while reading character by character. In short I want to know how to find an  empty line while reading char by char. Let me know if anything is unclear with a comment.
Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either collect the characters of the current line in a buffer and then count when you see the end of line.

```
$buffer = '';
while (($char = fgetc($fp)) !== false) {
    if ($char != '\n') {
        $buffer .= $char;
    } else {
        if (strlen($buffer) == 0) {
            echo "Empty line\n";
        } else {
            echo "Non-empty line\n";
        }

        $buffer = '';
    }
}
```

Or you keep a count of characters while you read, until you see the end of line

```
$count = 0;
while (($char = fgetc($fp)) !== false) {
    if ($char != '\n') {
        ++$count;
    } else {
        if ($count == 0) {
            echo "Empty line\n";
        } else {
            echo "Non-empty line\n";
        }

        $count = 0;
    }
}
```

As you can see, both versions are similar, it only depends on whether you need the line afterwards or not.

---

To consider `\r`, you can compensate when you see one immediately before a `\n`, e.g.

```
$cr = false;
$count = 0;
while (($char = fgetc($fp)) !== false) {
    if ($char != '\n') {
        $cr = false;
        ++$count;
        if ($char == "\r")
            $cr = true;
    } else {
        if ($cr)
            --$count;

        if ($count == 0) {
            echo "Empty line\n";
        } else {
            echo "Non-empty line\n";
        }

        $count = 0;
    }
}
```

`$cr` is true, if the previous character was a `\r`. So if you look at a newline and `$cr` is true, you have a `CRLF` and decrement the character count by one.

As an alternative, you can collect the whole line and trim whitespace before looking at the length

```
if (strlen(trim($buffer)) == 0) {
    echo "Empty line\n";
} else {
    echo "Non-empty line\n";
}
```

---

Even though not asked, reading a whole line and checking might be more efficient, e.g.

```
while (($buffer = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
    if (strlen(rtrim($buffer, "\n")) == 0) {
        echo "Empty line\n";
    } else {
        echo "Non-empty line\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you @Olaf Dietsche... The problem I encountered is that every line has an \n char at the end whether it be in the form of a \r\n or a single \n. So searching for a \n while fgetc() is not being sufficient. So since in each line there is a \n I cannot differentiate between an empty line and an endof line. Can you follow my draft? Regards

Comment: I just found out that my solution also did not work. So I am still waiting for answers. Regards Otag

Comment: Hello @Olaf Dietsche. I will check and let you know with a correct answer mark. Thank you...

Comment: Hello @Olaf Dietsche ... Thank you for your miscellaneous solutions. I finally made one work => if (strlen(trim($buffer)) != 0).... else{ echo "empty line";} Thanks again Otag